# Setting up GetSimple CMS with Nginx

Tags: web-hosting, cms, linux, nginx, localhost

I'm quite a noob in web, I'd like to setup a Linux(Debian) web server and decided to use GetSimple CMS and Nginx since I've found out that they'd give the best performance by using smallest resources.

I've set up Nginx and understood how it was serving the page but I couldn't get the CMS to work, I followed this guide with GPeasy CMS https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-gpeasy-cms-with-nginx-and-php5-fpm-on-debian-7 and changed everything with respect to GetSimple CMS but couldn't reach the admin page, from local host all I get is "This page is temporarily unavailable" and when I want to receive admin page by typing /localhost/admin it says:

The website at **http://admin/install.php** seems to be unavailable. The precise error was: *Cannot resolve hostname (admin)*

I'd be grateful if someone can guide me what should I do, I've checked GetSimple CMS forums but couldn't find anything that I can make use with this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some work, I've figure out how to set it up. Following the tutorial about GPeasy didn't work at all, this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7QXnk8emzOU and documentation of nginx worked well since the only require thing to serve the index page of GetSimple CMS which is a php file, so by setting php5-fpm to read all .php extended files in the root from the nginx's configuration file worked well.